# Socket.Poll has wildly varying delay on different machines

Tags: .net, sockets

I've got a .net 2.0 client app I've inherited that uses sockets.  Server is running on an iSeries.  I've got computers that try to use the client app and are experiencing lag. On a computer experiencing "lag" I've determined that the Socket.Poll method is taking longer.

Here is how(i think) I know.

```
MyApp.WriteLogEntry("CS: START check for readable socket");
start = DateTime.Now;
readable = ControllerSocket.Poll(500, SelectMode.SelectRead);
end = DateTime.Now;
MyApp.WriteLogEntry("CS: END check for readable socket");
elapsed = end.Subtract(start);
MyApp.WriteLogEntry("Elapsed TotalMilliseconds = " + elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
```

log from a computer with no lag

```
10.04.22.994427|CS: START check for readable socket
10.04.22.997427|CS: END check for readable socket
10.04.22.997427|Elapsed TotalMilliseconds = 1.0001
```

log from a computer with lag

```
10.03.30.729816|CS: START check for readable socket
10.03.30.745432|CS: END check for readable socket
10.03.30.745432|Elapsed TotalMilliseconds = 15.6152
```

Both computer are windows 7 64 bit. One is a fresh copy from the disk (no lag), other computer is corporate image(lag). Both computers are gigabit ethernet.

I've disabled firewalls on both and they both are running Symantec Endpoint 12, configured identically. I've removed SEP all together and get the same result

Why the delay? Registry setting? Ninja Gremlins?

EDIT
switch out to use the stopwatch class for timing

```
MyApp.WriteLogEntry("CS: START check for readable socket");
stopwatch.Start();
readable = ControllerSocket.Poll(500, SelectMode.SelectRead);
stopwatch.Stop();
MyApp.WriteLogEntry("Elapsed TotalMilliseconds = " + stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());            
MyApp.WriteLogEntry("CS: END check for readable socket");   

11.27.30.012079|CS: START check for readable socket
11.27.30.013079|Elapsed TotalMilliseconds = 00:00:00.0000696
11.27.30.013079|CS: END check for readable socket

11.28.30.518912|CS: START check for readable socket
11.28.30.534512|Elapsed TotalMilliseconds = 00:00:00.0148936
11.28.30.534512|CS: END check for readable socket
```

GOOD READ:http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/08/windows-timer-resolution-megawatts-wasted/

Comment: 15ms? That doesn't sound like an unreasonable value for network communication... If that's a lag that's noticeable to end users, maybe the problem really is somewhere else? For example, using a new connection for each communication or something like that? Oh, and `DateTime.Now` isn't precise enough for this. The default precision is only around those 15ms, so those two might actually take the same amount of time, recorded differently based on luck. Or maybe on the "non lag" computer you've got higher timer precision (thanks to some stupid application).

Comment: this app does this same read/error poll 755 times during login. run the math and it's bout 12 seconds

Comment: Do a wireshark sniff & analyse if there is any delay in receiving @ TCP layer?

Comment: Tried that. Network is fast.

Comment: You're polling 755 times during login? That's exactly what I meant when saying that perhaps the problem is somewhere else - in your design. Is that a TCP connection? Why do you need to poll 755 times during the login? What are you actually trying to do there? Perhaps it would be a better idea to use either asynchronous I/O or blocking reads with timeouts instead of polling like this?

Comment: Also, how does e.g. ping work on both machines? Is the delay also different there? And trying some HTTP connections, for example?

Comment: Inherited the app. redesign is not an option. The fact that the application works "fast" with a "stock windows" installation too me points to a workstation configuration

Comment: it polls twice for the login (1 to check error, 1 to check for readable socket). There is a bucket of literals and menu option that get generated from the server to the windows form. That is why the large number of polls. Sry to mislead you. I just don't understand the long poll times for the imaged(non stock) windows installation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is actually the "fast" machine that is misbehaving.  Timers in Windows have a resolution that's determined by the clock interrupt rate.  A properly configured machine ticks 64 times per second, that makes the accuracy of a timer 15.625 msec.  The normal state of the processor between ticks is to be powered-off, stopped on a [HLT instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLT).  During which it of course can't observe time passing by.

You can usually find the program that causes the machine to misbehave by running `powercfg.exe /energy` from an elevated command report.  This usually pinpoints a media related program, audio drivers or plugins are often to blame.  Google's Chrome is notorious for doing this, even on [battery-powered devices](http://blog.codinghorror.com/why-does-windows-have-terrible-battery-life/), worst possible thing you could do to battery life.

The resolution suggested by Socket.Poll() is of course greatly overstated, this comes from the underlying [select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) socket function.  Dates back to Unix in the 1980s when sockets were invented, power consumption was definitely not a concern back then.

This *ought* to not be a problem, after all there was nothing to do so it should not matter how long it took.  And you should not in general use the method but rely on asynchronous I/O with Socket.BeginSend/Receive(), very efficient.  If you look for a quick fix then you can do the evil thing as well and reprogram the clock interrupt rate.  You have to pinvoke the [timeBeginPeriod() function](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winmm/timeBeginPeriod.html).  Ask for 1 msec.  And pinvoke timeEndPeriod() when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Very informative. What I am failing to understand is why the stock windows installation is not laggy and the corporate image is laggy. From what I see from your explanation, that would explain the stated time difference and not the actual observed lag. Thanks

Comment: Well, sounds like you didn't run the powercfg.exe command I recommended.  It tells you the "why", I can't help you if you don't try that.  Ask more questions about it at superuser.com

Comment: I did run powercfg.exe /energy and it generated an html report. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Platform Timer Resolution:Outstanding Timer Request section.  Ask more question about it at superuser.com

Comment: Platform Timer Resolution:Platform Timer Resolution
The default platform timer resolution is 15.6ms (15625000ns) and should be used whenever the system is idle. If the timer resolution is increased, processor power management technologies may not be effective. The timer resolution may be increased due to multimedia playback or graphical animations.
Current Timer Resolution (100ns units) 156000

Comment: I think you were correct after all. My lack of understanding the problem.  Some other application must be cranking up the Platform Timer Resolution. In the case of the "Laggy" computer, I played something using windows media player on the imaged computer and then launched the application and it was just as fast as the stock windows disk computer.

Answer (score 2):

You are observing the Windows timer resolution. By default, it is about 15ms. Some programs turn it up to 1ms. It is not always at such a high value in order to drain the battery less.

Use the `Stopwatch` class.

Comment: @nkuebelbeck 15ms is still weird... it might be that the computer doesn't support the high precision timer `Stopwatch` uses. But if you're getting such long overall login time, that probably isn't the case.

Comment: @nkuebelbeck maybe sleeping in Windows is bounded by the timer resolution as well. It probably is. You need a different design if you rely on polling for 500 **micro**seconds. Why are you doing that? Poll for zero or use a more modern non-blocking IO model such as await or the begin/end style.